# C# Up Down Arrow for Next/Previous in a string list/collection

Tags: c#, winforms, list, keyboard, stringcollection

I am a bit confused here:

**Windows Forms Application, in C#.**

Let's say I have a text box.  And when the user enters text into that text box, and submits that to the server, it populates what the user wrote into an internal `List<string>`.

Now, let's say that when a user presses like `ctrl + UP` on the keyboard, that I want it to return the LAST message they typed (which is essentially the last message added to the `List<string>` collection.

And if the user presses `ctrl + Down` on the keyboard, it should return the previous message that occurred before the last `up` was pressed.

But, oddly, i'm utterly confused as to how to implement this.  LOL i know it's like uber simple, but strangely, i can't seem to figure it out.

```
inputPublicHistory[inputPublicHistory.Count - 1]
```

Seems like a logical method to pull the previous history, like when i press 'up'.  But, obviously, w/o a method to track where that index is, it's hard to compare.

```
inputPublicHistoryIndex +=1
```

I could add that after a the user presses the `Ctrl + Up` on the keyboard, to increment the index, and just return that result, but is that really a valid/proper way to do this?

Maybe i'm just overthinking this, perhaps one of you awesome people here could help me get my h ead screwed on straight with such a simple task.

Comment: @HenkHolterman _"...submits that to the server..."_ seems to be ASP.NET-related.

Comment: i apologize, when i get frazzled, i forget to mention what the heck i'm working on lol.  Sorry about that, edited the above to show what it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do pretty much what you have outlined except when you save the user's latest input, set the index tracking where they are to .Count - 1. If they press CTRL+Up and the index is at .Count - 1, show them the last item in the list. If they then press CTRL+Down, decrement the index and show them that item, but don't (obviously) go below 0.

Comment: Yup, worked fine lol.  I just needed someone to state it for me, so my head would be clear again.  Offda, sometimes going through all of this code can seem so daunting.  Thanks again.